# Military to Standard Conversion (Add space between time and AM/PM)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm converting military to standard and I was wondering if there is a way to get a space between the time itself and the AM/PM notation when converting (Please don't mind the variables. The time itself is coming from the user)

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME(0) = @EncTime;
DECLARE @MinutesToAdd INT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Minutes)
DECLARE @SetEndTime VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT DATEADD(Minute, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime) AS EndTime)

SET @Converted = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(Minute, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime), 100) AS EndTime)
```

Comment: If you're just converting "input from the user", why do it in SQL? Practically any application language can do this with ease. SQL is ill suited to the task (as you can see).

Comment: It would help if you showed the formats of the strings you are working with.

Comment: Could you give a solid example of what you mean by "military to standard"? Like "20:09" to "8:09 PM"?

Comment: Not relevant to your current problem, but please [read this about using `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later you can use the FORMAT() function.  Your last line would then look like this:

```
select format(cast(DATEADD(Minute, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime) as datetime), 'hh\:mm tt')
```

MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Just be aware [`FORMAT()` is an absolute dog, performance-wise](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). If this is for the presentation tier, why not perform `.format()` in the presentation language?

Comment: It CAN be an absolute dog, but if it is just being used to set a value based on some input as is suggested by the sample query, it is essentially a 0ms operation.  I agree on doing stuff like this in presentation logic btw, just going off of what was supplied by the OP.

Comment: So use FORMAT in this case, but then use other methods when performance is important? I prefer consistency. YMMV.

Comment: YMMV back 'atcha.  I prefer to do things that make sense.  Suppose a carpenter decided to use only a hammer for consistency.  Good idea?  YMMV...

Comment: That's an absolutely terrible analogy. We're not carpenters using physical tools to accomplish a wide variety of physical tasks. We're writing code that other people learn from, and it's important to point out when something might be "ok" in one case and total crap in others. That's all I was doing.

Comment: ...and I agreed with you, it was your second comment where you made it sound like using the right tool for the job/method means always using the same tool/method because you sacrifice consistency otherwise.  The right solution/tool might be the FORMAT function, and it might not - it depends what is being built, enforced coding standards, etc.  That is more of a philosophical debate/opinion and generally not constructive here.  Side note, 99.9% of the time I will take performance, and I appreciate you linking that article.